# Как узнать прокручен ли скролл в определенном диве

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно узнать, прокручен ли *скролл* (не *скролл* страницы, а *скролл* дива) до определенного, допустим `li:last-chield`, элемента?

Answer (score 1):

Просто обрабатывайте событие скролла на нужном блоке.

Что то вроде этого:

```
$('селектор блока').scroll(function () {
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
});
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/13qohht6/

Насчет узнать до какого элемента он прокручен, все зависит от ситуации. Как вариант просто сравнивать позицию скролла с позицией нужного дочернего элемента.